# chrome extension: keyboard shortcuts only work when background page has focus

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm creating a Chrome extension, and as I'm testing keyboard shortcuts I'm trying to log a message to the console when the user enters the shortcut. I'm having two weird problems, though. I've included the text of `manifest.json` and `background.js` below.

1. The keyboard shortcut only works when the background page has focus. If I click the link next to "inspect views" in the chrome extensions page and open the background page, the keyboard shortcut works fine while that page has focus. But the shortcut doesn't log anything to the console if I use it while another chrome window has focus.
2. If I edit the manifest to change the name or key combination of the shortcut, and reload the extension, it stops working. No traceback or error messages, just nothing. I have to uninstall and reinstall the extension to get it working again. Is there a way to avoid this strange behavior?

Here's the relevant text of manifest.json:

```
"commands": {
     "do_something": {
       "suggested_key": {
         "default": "Ctrl+Shift+U"
       },
       "description": "Toggle feature foo"
     }
```

And here's my background.js:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener(function(command) {
 console.log('Command:', command);
});
```

Here's the background section of my manifest:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-2.1.4.min.js", "background.js"],
    "persistent": false
},
```

If it's relevant, I'm running Chrome 43.

Comment: 1. Just to make sure: nothing is printed in console of the background page  (the correct place) or in the current tab's console? 2. Make sure no other extension uses `Ctrl-Shift-U` by creating a new empty profile with only your extension because checking keyboard shortcuts in chrome://extensions isn't enough

Comment: That's right, nothing is printed in the background page's console. I'll try creating a new profile with no extensions and see if that does the trick.

Comment: Are you sure your system doesn't already have a use for ctrl+shift+u? On Chrome OS, that is the shortcut for "Input Unicode characters".

Comment: I tried it with ctrl+shift+0, and ctrl+shift+y which my system doesn't have assigned. Same thing - works in the background page, not in other browser windows.

Comment: and @wOxxOm I tried running it with an empty profile just to check. Still encountering the same issues :/

Comment: What's the `background` section of your manifest?

Comment: @Xan added the `background` section

Comment: Well, with `persistent: false` console logs can get lost as the page unloads.

Comment: Hm. okay I'll try it with persistent: true

Comment: Sorry about the delay, but I figured it out - it turns out that my system has Ctrl-Shift-0 (zero) assigned to something, not sure what. It works with Ctrl-Shift-7, though.